# Add two arrays Java

Tags: java, arrays, sum

I want to add elements of two array in Java. I wrote this code:

```
public static void sum (int [] a; int [] b){

    int sum=new sum[a.length];

    for (int i=0;a.length;i++){
        sum[i]=a[i]+b[i];
    }
}
```

this code doesn't work, because sum only the first element of two arrays. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: this code wont run and has a few syntacitcal errors, as your loop condition or using a `;` to seperate the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void sum (int [] a, int [] b){ //, instead of ;

   //instead of int sum = new sum[a.length]; 
   int[] sum = new int[a.length]; 

  //i < a.length isntead of a.length
  for (int i=0; i < a.length; i++){
    sum[i] = a[i] + b[i];
  }
}
```

Extended version for arrays with different length:

```
public static void sum (int [] a, int [] b){

   int[] sum = new int[Math.max(a.length, b.length)]; 

  for (int i=0; i < sum.length; i++){
    sum[i] = (i < a.length ? a[i] : 0) + (i < b.length ? b[i] : 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: I mistyped the code, I wrote for (int i=0; i < a.length; i++){

Comment: What if both arrays are of different length?

Comment: @mhasan, updated)

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] sum = new int[a.length]
```

should work. there is no datatype "sum"

and of course,

```
i < a.length
```

Comment: and as Kevin Esche said, your params should be seperated with , not ;

Comment: thanks Pavneet Singh